# Two trigger calls calling mutually

Tags: mysql, database, database-trigger

so I have this two tables which both have some trigger, both are AFTER INSERT; I dont exactly know how to call it but I hope the title is not so inaccurate. :)
I'm currently new to triggers in general so bear with me on this one please.
What happens is that for every new episode entry I need to updated the count of episodes per season. And when a new entry in the season table a new episode shall be created (a trailer).
I'm currently using MySQL 5.7.17; This triggers work in DB2 but in MySQL I just couldnt get them to work.
I just keep getting the error that says that I can't update the table from which the statement was called:

> Can't update table 'seasons' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

If you can help me, or not, anyways any ideas THANKS IN ADVANCE!

```
CREATE TABLE episodes (
  episodeId INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  seasonId INTEGER NOT NULL,
  number INTEGER NOT NULL,
  date DATE NOT NULL,
  title VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
  summary TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY(episodeId)
);

CREATE TABLE seasons (
  seasonId INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  startDate DATE NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT 'Unknown season',
  numberOfEpisodes SMALLINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY(seasonId)
);

/* TRIGGERS */
/* trigger to increment the numberOfEpisodes in seasons */
CREATE TRIGGER newEpisode
  AFTER INSERT ON episodes
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN  -- I also tried without the Begin-End statement
    UPDATE seasons SET numberOfEpisodes = numberOfEpisodes + 1
    WHERE seasons.seasonId = NEW.seasonId;
  END;
;

/* Each season has a trailer as episode 0 */
CREATE TRIGGER newSeason
  AFTER INSERT ON seasons
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN -- I also tried without the Begin-End statement
    INSERT INTO episodes (seasonId, number, date, title, summary)
      VALUES (NEW.seasonId, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'Trailer', 'Episode 0 = Trialer');
  END;
;
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't closed loops in triggers like this: Inserting into `seasons` triggers an insert on `episodes`, which triggers an update of `seasons`. My recommendation is to get rid of the trigger on `seasons` and insert the trailer in your code.

Comment: I would actually get rid of the trigger on `episodes` too (and the column `numberOfEpisodes`) and calculate the value on the fly when you need it by just counting the episodes. Such dependencies are signs of a bad design. If you really really really want to do it anyway against all advice, you could skip the update when you insert the trailer, e.g. by adding `if new.number > 0 then update seasons set ... `; you will have to insert the new season with a value of 1 for `numberOfEpisodes`, because it will now not be incremented when the trailer gets inserted.

Comment: Yea, at the beginning I thought about removing the numberOfEpisodes, because is non-sense at some degree, sadly this is what I have to deal with :(
Anyways thanks for the advice, I think I'll just take away the numberOfEpisode column and calculate it by a count statement